# How to use dynamic sort with pagable in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, sorting, search

I want to build a search algorithm in Spring boot.
I have a **Company Entity** and I would like to get a collection with pagination.
I want to sort the collection based on a calculated **relevance value** which is calculated from values mapped with the  **CompanyEntity**, such as how many reviews the company has, average review, owner activity.

```
Specification<CompanyEntity> specification = CompanySpecification.build(searchDto);
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(searchDto.getPage(),PAGE_SIZE,utility.sortBuilder(searchDto));
Page<CompanyEntity> companyEntities = companyRepository.findAll(specification,pageable);
```

Sorting the collection after getting it from the repository is too slow.
I tried using Sort objects but i can sort only by column names. Do i have to calculate this relevance value in the SQL level or there is a already made up solution for this in Spring?
Ty.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can consider is to calculate the relevance value in your Java code after fetching the data and then sort the results. This way, you have more flexibility in defining the relevance calculation logic. However, as you mentioned, sorting the collection in memory after fetching it from the repository might be slow, especially when dealing with large datasets.

To optimize this process, you can consider using PriorityQueue along with a custom comparator that considers the calculated relevance value. This allows you to keep the collection sorted efficiently while fetching data. For example:

```
// Define your custom comparator for the priority queue
Comparator<CompanyEntity> relevanceComparator = (company1, company2) -> {
    // Calculate relevance values for company1 and company2
    double relevance1 = calculateRelevance(company1);
    double relevance2 = calculateRelevance(company2);
    
    // Compare based on relevance values
    return Double.compare(relevance2, relevance1); // Reverse order for higher relevance first
};

PriorityQueue<CompanyEntity> sortedCompanies = new PriorityQueue<>(relevanceComparator);

// Fetch data and add to the priority queue
for (CompanyEntity company : companyEntities) {
    double relevance = calculateRelevance(company);
    company.setRelevance(relevance); // Store the calculated relevance in the entity
    sortedCompanies.offer(company);
}

// Paginate the sorted results
List<CompanyEntity> paginatedResults = new ArrayList<>();
int startIndex = searchDto.getPage() * PAGE_SIZE;
int endIndex = startIndex + PAGE_SIZE;
for (int i = 0; i < startIndex && !sortedCompanies.isEmpty(); i++) {
    sortedCompanies.poll(); // Discard companies before the desired page
}
for (int i = startIndex; i < endIndex && !sortedCompanies.isEmpty(); i++) {
    paginatedResults.add(sortedCompanies.poll());
}
```

Although this approach requires more memory to store the priority queue, it can be much more efficient than sorting the entire collection in memory.